# Docker build context puzzle

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My project structure:

```
projectRoot/
   - service/ 
     - data.json
     - Dockerfile
```

In that `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.14

ENV THE_DATA=/tmp/data.json

COPY data.json /tmp/data.json
```

Under project root, if I build the image:

```
docker build -t service:data_tmp -f service/Dockerfile .
```

I get error:

```
 => ERROR [2/2] COPY data.json /tmp/data.json 
...
failed to compute cache key: "/data.json" not found: not found
```

I guess the error is due to the last `.` indicates build context is project root, that's why the `data.json` can't be located.

(**My 2nd try**) Then, I changed the `Dockerfile` to:

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.14

ENV THE_DATA=/tmp/data.json

COPY ./service/data.json /tmp/data.json
```

But get error:

```
=> ERROR [2/2] COPY ./service/data.json /tmp/data.json 
...
failed to compute cache key: "/service/data.json" not found: not found
```

(**My 3rd try** successful) I managed to make it eventually build successfully by changing the build context to `/service/`:

```
docker build -t service:data_tmp -f service/Dockerfile /service/
```

But I don't get why my **2nd try** above is not working? I mean in my 2nd try, even though build context is still `.` meaning current directory, meaning project root, then, the path `COPY` from `./service/data.json` should be correct. Why I still get error there?

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` inside `.`?

Comment: Yes, I have `.dockerignore`

Comment: @BMitch, thanks, I solved my problem by adding `!service` in `.dockerignore`. Can you make an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When files that exist on the filesystem are not found in a `COPY` step, check two things:

1. Your context, which was done here. That's the `.` at the end of the build command saying the context is the current directory. If you pass a different directory, that is the source for `COPY` steps (at least those that don't change the source with a `--from`).
2. A `.dockerignore` file. This is in the root of the context, and has a syntax similar to `.gitignore`. When changing the context, you change the location docker checks for the `.dockerignore` file.

A common pattern for a minimal docker build is to specify the `.dockerignore` file with:

```
*
!src
# ...
```

Which tells docker to exclude everything on the first line, and then reinclude `src` on the second line. You would add additional lines to reinclude the folder here with `!service`.